# Javascript order function with override value

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a set of rows I return from a database. They are returned in the form `(media_id,order,front_image)`. One of the `media` has a `front_image` value of `TRUE`. I then have a sort function like so:

```
.sort(function (m1, m2) {
  if (m1.order < m2.order) {
    val = -1;
  } else if (m1.order > m2.order) {
    val = 1;
  }
  return val;
})
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to guarantee that if a `media` has a `front_image` value of `TRUE`, it will be the first in the array. I tried adding it as an or statement within the sortFunction but this did not produce the correct results.

Comment: Post the mentioned data.

Comment: Is TRUE the boolean `true`? Or is it a string `"TRUE"`?

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Since boolean values coerce to number values 0 (`false`) and 1 (`true`), you could sort like this:

```
.sort(function (m1, m2) {
    return (m2.front_image - m1.front_image) || (m1.order - m2.order);
})
```

But if the value to give priority is a string `"TRUE"`, then you could just turn that into a boolean expression like this:

```
.sort(function (m1, m2) {
    return ((m2.front_image=="TRUE") - (m1.front_image=="TRUE")) || (m1.order - m2.order);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```js
var input = [
  {front_image: false, order: 4},
  {front_image: false, order: 2},
  {front_image: true, order: 3},
  {front_image: false, order: 1},
  {front_image: false, order: 0}
]

var output = input.sort(function (l, r) {
  return (r.front_image - l.front_image)
      || (l.order - r.order)
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if `front_image` is `'TRUE'` and move the items to top, then sort by `order`.

```js
var data = [{ media_id: 1, order: 7, front_image: '' }, { media_id: 3, order: 6, front_image: '' }, { media_id: 6, order: 5, front_image: 'TRUE' }, { media_id: 4, order: 4, front_image: '' }, { media_id: 5, order: 3, front_image: 'TRUE' }, { media_id: 7, order: 2, front_image: '' }, { media_id: 8, order: 1, front_image: '' }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (b.front_image === 'TRUE') - (a.front_image === 'TRUE') || a.order - b.order;
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```